# What's Patty doing with all this grog?

Tags: risen-2

When I'm talking to Patty, there's an option to give her grog. I gave her a bunch and she didn't seem to act any different (not even slightly inebriated). What does giving grog to Patty accomplish, if anything? Do I have to give her a certain amount for anything to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grogs are basically health potions in this game. If you give Grog to Patty, she will use it when she's at low health.